# Creating sprites using php

Tags: php, image, sprite

Basically, I have my default css sprites already stored in my folder. What I really want now is allow the user to upload images and append that particular images at the end of my default sprites so that I can retrieve it for different purposes. How can I achieve this using PHP?

Comment: Check out [GD](http://php.net/book.image.php)!

Comment: Which part you want me to check there? Watermark? Captcha? Which part of GD library you want me to check?

Comment: The function reference! Specifically the one that loads your particular format of image, the one that creates a new image, the one that draws an image on an image, and the one that outputs an image in your desired format.

Comment: The reference of what? I've checked it many times.